# How to read Open-Liberty server config property file value in java class?

Tags: java, websphere-liberty, open-liberty

I have a scenario where I need to read an url from my property file I have created in a server config directory of my created server i.e. `C:\<path to liberty installation>\openliberty-21.0.0.11\wlp\usr\servers\TestServer\config\test.properties` . I have the property file content something like File :**test.properties**

```
downstream_service.url=https:\\abc_service.com
```

I need to read this url in my crated application's java class somehow and do some operation.This application  I am going to deploy in the above server .

e.g.

```
  public void myMethod(){
      String serviceUrl=<some logic to get >;
    }
```

Any suggestion would be appreciable to  read this value in property file.

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of ways to accomplish this, but the one I would recommend would be to leverage [MicroProfile Config](https://github.com/eclipse/microprofile-config), as it exists to do exactly what you want with a simple annotation, which would look something like:

```
@Inject
@ConfigProperty(name="downstream_service.url", 
               defaultValue="setIfApplicable")
private String serviceUrl;
```

Don't forget to include the [mpConfig-2.0 feature](https://openliberty.io/docs/latest/reference/feature/mpConfig-2.0.html) in your server.xml (or [mpConfig-3.0 or newer](https://openliberty.io/docs/latest/reference/feature/mpConfig.html) if you're already using the jakarta namespace).  You would then just need to choose one of the many ways to set the `downstream_service.url` property, which could be as easy as creating a file named `downstream_service.url` in `${server.config.dir}/variables` and setting its contents to `https:\\abc_service.com`. Reference the [Server Configuration](https://openliberty.io/docs/latest/reference/config/server-configuration-overview.html) doc for more information.

For more guidance on using mpConfig, take a look at [Separating configuration from code in microservices](https://openliberty.io/guides/microprofile-config-intro.html) and/or [Configuring microservices](https://openliberty.io/guides/microprofile-config.html) guides.

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution by tweaking some code.
I kept the path of properties file in `jvm.options` like `-Djava.test.properties=C:/Users/abc/openliberty-21.0.0.11/wlp/usr/servers/TestServer/config/test.properties` Then I was able to get this file path and I loaded this file using bellow code:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
    try {
        props.load(new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("java.test.properties")));
        System.out.println(props.getProperty("serviceurl"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```